# wildfly-maven-plugin:1.2.1.Final start and run do not work for remote host

Tags: wildfly-10, wildfly-maven-plugin

I have used wildfly-maven-plugin:1.2.1.Final and deploy,undeploy & shutdown all work for locally and also remotely.

The problem I is that the start and run goals do not work for a remote host. It seems like it does not use the same config for goals like deploy, undeploy & shutdown

Any ideas how I configure so that run or start work for remote host?

Thanks,

daslan

Answer (score 0):

The `wildfly-maven-plugin` cannot start a remote WildFly instance. With both the `start` and `run` goals the plugin starts a new process locally. There is no way, at least that I'm aware of, to start a new process on a remote machine.

The `deploy`, `redeploy`, `undeploy` and `shutdown` goals work because they send requests over the management API.